# Linux command to copy as hard links, while deleting unwanted files?

Tags: rsync, cp, file-copy, hard-link

I'm looking for a command that behaves both like

```
cp -al
```

in only creating hard links rather than copying file contents, and

```
rsync -a --delete
```

in removing files from the destination that are not present in the source. I've looked into `rsync` options related to hard links, but they don't seem able to *only* create hard links.

Does such a command exist on Linux?

Comment: Using rsync with `--link-dest` pointing to the source tree might do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you are working with directories, named 'src' and 'dest', for the source and destination of your copy, respectively.  You could use the following command pipe to eliminate destination files not present in the source:

```
find src/* dest/* |cut -d'/' -f2- |sort |uniq -u |xargs printf "dest/%s\n" |xargs rm -f
```

Beware that this only works if your file names don't contain whitespace or `\'"`.

Comment: `touch 'dest/ /home/user3443186'` → there go all your files. Manipulating file names like this only works if you know that your file names don't contain any special characters.